# KendoUI dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

It is possible to call a function (show div) if the user choose only the third value on the dropdownlist?

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var data = [
            {text: "Initial Notification", value:"1"},
            {text: "Update Notification", value:"2"},
            {text: "Final Notification", value:"3"}
            ];
            $("#notificationtype").kendoDropDownList({
                dataTextField: "text",
                dataValueField: "text",
                dataSource: data,
                height: 400
            });

            var dropdownlist = $("#notificationtype").data("kendoDropDownList");
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to make it as

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var data = [
            {text: "Initial Notification", value:"1"},
            {text: "Update Notification", value:"2"},
            {text: "Final Notification", value:"3"}
            ];
            $("#notificationtype").kendoDropDownList({
                dataTextField: "text",
                dataValueField: "text",
                dataSource: data,
                height: 400,
                change: function() {
                   var notificationstate = $("#notificationtype").val();
                   if (notificationstate == "Final Notification") {
                       $('#finaltime').show();
                   } else{
                       $ ('#finaltime').hide();
                   }
                }
            });
            var dropdownlist = $("#notificationtype").data("kendoDropDownList");
        });
```